# Why does the joining of two strings produce a type error?

Tags: python

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, parent, daughters, edge):
        self.parent = parent
        self.daughters = daughters
        self.edge = edge
        trie.append(self)
        self.index = len(trie) - 1
        trie[parent].daughters.append(self.index)
    ...

    def SuffixTreeConstruction():
    global trie
    print(len(trie))
    for node in trie:
        if len(node.daughters) == 1:
            node.edge = ''.join([node.edge, trie[node.daughters[0]].edge])
            ...
```

I want to take the edges of two different nodes and combine them as a string. The edges are iterations of a string (`for base in text: create node with base as edge`), so I assume they are single character strings, not characters (with numerical values). However, they are apparently integers. Is there any evident reason for this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trieMatching.1.py", line 149, in <module>
    SuffixTreeConstruction()
  File "trieMatching.1.py", line 106, in SuffixTreeConstruction
    node.edge = ''.join([node.edge, trie[node.daughters[0]].edge])
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: Seems like you have an int, and not a string

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it is possible that either of node.edge or trie[node.daughters[0]].edge] is of type `<type 'int'>`
So try typecasting them into string by,

```
node.edge = ''.join([str(node.edge), str(trie[node.daughters[0]].edge]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid typecasting is to use the `format` string to get the same result"

```
node.edge = '{0}{1}'.format(node.edge, trie[node.daughters[0]].edge)
```

The typecasting will be done for you. The added benfit is that you can format things anyway you like... see `format` [docs and examples](http://pyformat.info/)